# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$, denote $A(V)$ as $Hom(V, V)$. Find the set of commutative linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$, denote $A(V)$ as $Hom(V, V)$. Let $Z = \{T \in A(V) | ST=TS  \quad  \forall S \in A(V) \}$

Prove $Z$ merely consists of the multiple of unit element of $A(V)$ by the elements of $F$

One direction is easy, namely set of multiple of unit element of $A(V)$ by the elements of $F$ is contained in $Z$

However, for the reversed direction, I'm stuck.

For I get so far:

Let $T \in Z$ and write $T = I + W$ where $I$ is the unit element and $W \in A(V)$, then we can show that $W \in Z$

Any hints for the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T\in Z$. 
Assume there exists $v\in V$ with $w:=Tv\notin Fv$.
There exists $S$ that maps $w\mapsto v$, $v\mapsto 0$ (and whatever elsewhere).
Then $TSv=T0=0$ and $STv=Sw=v\ne 0$, contradicting $T\in Z$.
Hence, for each $v\in V$, there exists $\lambda_v$ with $Tv=\lambda_vv$.
Let $v,w\in V$ be linearly Independent and $u=v+w$. 
Then $u,w$ are linearly Independent and we have
$$ \lambda_u u =Tu=Tv+Tw=\lambda_v v+ \lambda_w w=\lambda_v u+(\lambda_w-\lambda_v)w,$$
hence $\lambda_w-\lambda_v=0$.
We conclude that $\lambda_v$ is the same for all (non-zero) $v$, hence $T=\lambda_v\operatorname{Id}$.

Answer (score 0):

I only know that T is a scalar mapping when V has finite dimensions. Here is the solution. 
Suppose that $\dim V =n$ Let ${v_i}$ be the basis. Define $S_{ij}$ as a linear mapping that projects the ith element to the jth, i. e. $S_{1,2}(x_1, x_2, x_3) =(0, x_1, 0)$.  After i and j run from 1 to n independently,  we deduce that T is a scalar linear mapping. 
It might be much more clear when referring to matrices form of the linear mapping.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention V has finite dimensions